# t-test/regression - how to account for random effects?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, mixed-model

I need your help on how best to test the following hypotheses in R. Each observation in my data has `RaterID` and `RaterGender`, along with their ratings on 5-point scale for four different attributes (`P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`) of product (`ProductID`).There are multiple observations for each rater and same product may have ratings from multiple observers.

How do I statistically model in R to test the following hypothesis:

*H1: Men are more likely have higher ratings on `P1` than `P2`.*

*H2: Women are more likely to have higher ratings on `P4` than `P3`.*

How should I control for the random effects of raters and products?

Comment: But you haven't told us anything about how the data were collected.

Comment: Data was collected through a survey following product purchases by the individuals. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Survey data needs to be carefully handled.  You cannot just build traditional mixed effects models or carry out traditional hypothesis tests.  How does each observation have multiple ratings?  You need to tell us more about the data collection process and I'd exercise caution using any of the answers provided thus far since this information is absent in your question and this can change the entire analysis.

Comment: The setup is such that people buy products listed on a website. After each product purchase, they take a small survey on the four product attributes. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: What is the population of interest?  You should update the question with these additional details and then I'll delete some of the comments with my questions.

Comment: These are organic products. So the population of interest is consumers who buy organic products. I am trying to understand of there are gender differences in the preferences of such consumers.

Comment: How are you able to measure all consumers?  It seems to me you are only collecting data on consumers to your website.  How are you capturing data from other websites and retail store purchases?

Comment: Yes, I only have access to data on one website.

Comment: So, unless that website was randomly selected from all websites, then it will be impossible for you to infer anything about all consumers who buy organic products.  Research shows that online buyers are markedly different than those who purchase items in retail, brick-and-mortar stores.  I doubt consumers have similar behavior from web-site to web-site at that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, you could start from a model that contains as fixed effects the sex and the attribute, where sex is a factor with levels male and female, and attribute a factor with levels P1-P4, and random effects for ProductID and RaterID, e.g., something like

```
y ~ sex * attribute + (1 | ProductID) + (1 | RaterID)
```

By including the interaction, you could test your specific hypothesis of interest by using suitable contrasts.

An additional important point is what type of mixed model you will use. If I understood correctly, you have an ordinal outcome (i.e., 5-point scale). There are not that many options with regard to software for proportional odds models. However, you could use the continuation ratio model instead that requires a couple of extra data management steps, and fitting the model with a mixed effects logistic regression.

Comment: (+1) perhaps a cumulative link mixed model with `clmm2` from the `ordinal` package would be suitable - although I am not sure if it handles crossed random effects.

Comment: How does this take into account finite population corrections or the survey design?

Comment: @RobertLong I also don’t know about the **ordinal** package, but I’ve been using the continuation ratio model with satisfactory results. In this model it is straightforward to check the ordinality assumption for specific covariates by simply including an interaction term.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test.  In R if your data is in data frame **X** with **X\$gender** being the gender data and **X\$difference** being the *difference* between the rating of $P_i$ versus $P_j$ then your code would be

> wilcox.test(difference~gender, data=X)

the null would be that there is no gender-based difference.

You would control for product effects by solving it for each product.  However, as you are doing multiple comparisons, you will need to add the FSA library to get the Holm-Bonferroni correction.

Run each test and capture the p-values into some variable such as calling it **pvalues**.  Then you would run

> final_values$Holm = p.adjust(pvalues, method = "holm")

Unless you know what the random effects are, you cannot control for them. There isn't a simple answer as to adding a variable for nonparametric anova that I have found.  The Friedman test may be appropriate, but you would have to research it appropriateness for your data.

Comment: what do you mean *"You would control for product effects by solving it for each product"* ? If you mean splitting the dataset by product then this would lead to an enormous loss of power. Also, the data are clustered by rater, not just product, so a mixed effects model with crossed random effects suggested by @DimitrisRizopoulos might be more appropriate....

Comment: I too had the same concern

Comment: Yes, I do need to rewrite that or at least qualify it.